# good webservice for gold rates

Tags: php, web-services

I am developing a jewellery website for my client. And he want to show gold rate as per the current day. So i am looking for a good webservice that returns this...

Comment: You're starting to attract close-as-offtopic votes. I'm not sure where would be the best place to ask this sorry. I'd suggest you contact a gold exchange e.g. http://www.ncdexspot.com/profile.aspx (found via Google, no specific recommendation) and ask them about getting hold of a feed or pointing you to one of their existing partners who can provide you one. But if it's really just a single day price you're after it might be simpler to cheekikly scrape it off another site e.g. http://www.indiatbd.com/

Comment: Here's a better way to display it (3 different styles): https://miningstockvaluator.com/live-gold-price.php

Comment: This would be an acceptable question at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know if you want the rate real-time or not, but there are several web services available:

- [xignite](http://www.xignite.com/xMetals.asmx)
- [Currency Convertor web service (free, check the terms of usage before using the web service in your app.)](http://www.webservicex.net/WS/WSDetails.aspx?WSID=10)

Comment: If you follow my comment further up on the page, you just have to copy and paste the code to display it. Easy as that...

Comment: xignite it's not free. Can you privde a free api link.